# Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 Pro - Can I encrypt both OS's at the same time with Bitlocker + LUKS

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I have alaptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and Win 10 Pro installed. Currently both are unencrypted as I had to remove Bitlocker to install Ubuntu alongside Win 10 Boot Manager. Is there a way I can use Bitlocker on Wİndows and LUKS or another thing with TPM support) on Ubuntu to encrypt both drives? I have found this guide on enabling Bitlocker with Ubuntu dual boot: https://itsfoss.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-bitlocker/ and I have found this guide for how to encrypt Ubuntu post installation: https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-encrypt-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-post-installation. However I couldn't find any information online as to if I can do these things at the same time, and I couldnt find a guide that encrypts both Ubuntu and Windows with the TPM (Bitlocker). All I could find was a guide on encrypting Windows with Veracrypt, which asks for a password at boot instead of using the TPM.

I can use Ubuntu with a passphrase on boot if that's what I have to do (though seemless TPM support like Bitlocker would be nice), but I have to use Bitlocker on Wİndows, and even though I can eneable it with Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot and it seems to be working fine, I want to have both of them encrypted for security purposes.

Can I encrypt both Ubuntu 22.04 and Win 10 Pro dual boot, and have it play nicely with GRUB (I could also use the windows boot manager and add linux there, if that'll work, but I want to have the OS choice on startup - not through BIOS or boot menu)

Basically -I want to use Bitlocker on Wİn 10 Pro simultaneously with the deafult encryption Ubuntu provides during startup.

Comment: This is absolutely possible but I recommend that you use separate drives or, if on one drive, choose either Bitlocker/LUKS. 

On a Thinkpad P50 with two drives, one for linux and one for windows, I boot through GRUB after decrypting the linux drive, on which the bootloader exists. I can then choose to boot Windows and decrypt Bitlocker at that point. 

I can confirm both drives are encrypted; that said, I don't recommend this setup, as Bitlocker and TPM don't play too nicely if you're frequently switching between systems. I often have to type in a recovery key to access windows...

Comment: 1) Thanks a lot for your answer. As this is a lapotop with no free m.2 or sata slots, I cannot use a sepearte drive in the long run (i sometimes need both Linux and Windows on the go). It seems I'll just use Bitlocker as Windows partition is where *most* of my important documents are, but I would like to encrypt both as I am the type of person that'll like to keep pivacy at the maximum.

Comment: 2) I can enter a recovery key every now and then, so can you please elaborate on how to get both encryption systems running? Can I just enable Bitlocker with the help of the first Link I wrote, and then enable encryption on Ubuntu just like normal? Will GRUB just accept that and work? OR do I have to follow a 
specific procedure? I will be very grateful if you could provide me with the basic steps to achieve this (or confirm that normal setup following the links would work)                              Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I can't speak for the accuracy but at first glance this guide looks to be high quality: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html

Comment: 1) I'm less familiar with Bitlocker but it appears geared towards full-disk encryption, so you'd need to decrypt your full disk (encrypted with Bitlocker) prior to accessing disk partitions. Here are some docs on the topic https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-device-encryption-overview-windows-10. 

2) My setup is specific to two separate disks so sounds like it's not relevant to your setup. 

AFAIK: _"Can I just enable Bitlocker with the help of the first Link I wrote, and then enable encryption on Ubuntu just like normal?"_

Yes

Comment: Lastly, as a different option for you, virtualization is very stable and performant in my experience via Virtualbox or built-in to Windows. And you can encrypt the entire virtual disk using LUKS. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I understand I can use a virtual machine but it seems that bare metal performance is necessary for me on both in certain applications so I'd rather dual boot. The first link you shared looks promising, but it explains a setup from scratch. I can enable Bitlocker with my current setup, but I am not sure if I can do it on Ubuntu using the steps provided in the link. The link encrypts partitions before ubuntu installation, can I encrypt it after the install as i currently have it installed, and will it work with GRUB like normal? - Thanks for your answers in advance